# MVVM Light register interface by key

Tags: c#, mvvm, dependency-injection, mvvm-light

I have modular WPF app. In each module I want have its own Messenger. Because I want send some messages inside module (without tokens).

First module:

```
namespace NS1
{
  public class MainViewModel : ViewModelBase
  {
    public MainViewModel(IMessenger messenger) : base(messenger)
    {
      .......            
    }   
  }
  public class Module1
  {
    Messenger Messenger1;
    static Module1()
    {
      Messenger1 = new Messenger();
      SimpleIoc.Default.Register<IMessenger>(() => Messenger1);
      SimpleIoc.Default.Register<MainViewModel>();
    }        
  }
}
```

And second module:

```
namespace NS2
{
  public class MainViewModel : ViewModelBase
  {
    public MainViewModel(IMessenger messenger) : base(messenger)
    {
      .......            
    }   
  }
  public class Module2
  {
    Messenger Messenger2;
    static Module2()
    {
      Messenger2 = new Messenger();
      SimpleIoc.Default.Register<IMessenger>(() => Messenger2);
      SimpleIoc.Default.Register<MainViewModel>();
    }        
  }
}
```

Of course i have error in line

```
SimpleIoc.Default.Register<IMessenger>(() => Messenger2);
```

How I can inject `Messenger1` to `MainViewModel` in `NS1` and `Messenger2` to `MainViewModel` in `NS2`?

Or is there other way? Tokens are good, but I must be sure that in different modules are no same tokens!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to register each separate instance of the Messenger interface with a key inside the SimpleIoc.

To get hold of the correct instance you'll also need to use the same key.
So constructor injecting will not be possible I'm afraid... you'll need to use the GetInstance method.

Code example is as follows

```
IMessenger m1 = new Messenger();
IMessenger m2 = new Messenger();

SimpleIoc.Default.Register<IMessenger>(() => m1, "Msg1");
SimpleIoc.Default.Register<IMessenger>(() => m2, "Msg2");

var t = SimpleIoc.Default.GetInstance<IMessenger>("Msg1");
var s = SimpleIoc.Default.GetInstance<IMessenger>("Msg2");
```